# Incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to NavigationDrawerFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I've been working on an app using API 14, but I had to downgrade to API 10. the app has fragments and activity fragments, I have imported the libraries and used the `getFragmentSupportManager` because it is v4. However, I have following error:

[image]

I created a dummy app with Drawer layout and fragments with API 10 from the beginning, it had the same line in `MyActivity` file and it was not an error. Here is my code:

```
package az.test2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Gravity;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
           getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager lolo;

        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragAV fav = new FragAV();
        FragW fw = new FragW();

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                FM.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fav).commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                FM.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fw).commit();
                break;
            case 2: break;
        }


        //FM.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();

    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
            restoreActionBar();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MyActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
}
```

I did everything I could but this error seems to be very rare. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I got the same problem .This [stack-overflow answer][1] solve my issue  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898996/how-to-solve-inconvertable-types-cannot-cast-android-support-v4-app-fragment-t

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using the support pack, your fragments should extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and not the regular Fragment class.

Comment: it is in the `import` section. should use the entire line every time I call the class?

Comment: No, just make sure your NavigationDrawerFragment class extends it. You might not have the import in its declaration.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm new to android development, I did not quite get what you mean by "extends it"

Comment: this is what he meant an eg is this from your own code PlaceholderFragment extends (Fragment) and he is saying make sure the said fragment extends the supportlibrary's fragment@EdZamrik

Comment: i did this `private class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment{}` and then `private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;` but at the line mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp it is saying cannot resolve method setUp() I think it is considering it a fragment and not a NavigationDrawerFragment anymore. did I do it right? @Elltz @zmbq

Comment: In the file with this line, do you have the proper using line (with android.support)?

Answer (score 2):

make sure your drawer fragment class extend 
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment
not fragment.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
```

to

```
Fragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
```

Comment: then try Zmbq's approach of extending the fragment from the right package

Answer (score 0):

in your mNavigationDrawerFragment class import 
"import  android.support.v4.app.Fragment;"
instead of  "import  android.app.Fragment;"