# How to solve inconvertable types cannot cast "Android.support.v4.app.fragment" to "packagename"

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am creating an android application that consists of navigation drawer in android studio.
I am getting an error called inconvertable types cannot cast **"How to solve inconvertable types cannot cast "Android.support.v4.app.fragment" to "packagename""** please helpme howto solve this.
This is my activity_main.java

```
package sample.lakshman.com.sampleltester;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import sample.lakshman.com.sampleltester.Fragment_navigation;




public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        Fragment_navigation drawer_navigation = (Fragment_navigation)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawer_navigation.setUp((DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.navigation_item)
        {
            Intent sub = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Subactivity.class);
            startActivity(sub);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_navigation"
        android:name="sample.lakshman.com.sampleltester.Fragment_navigation"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to NavigationDrawerFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386320/incompatible-types-fragment-cannot-be-converted-to-navigationdrawerfragment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just go to your Fragment_navigation class and
replace

**import android.app.Fragment;**

with

**import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;**

Comment: I m also facing same issue but have correct lib imported. Can u help me here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410161/actionbar-color-chooser-in-fragment-with-materialdailog-lib